# Android bitmap progressive blur

Tags: android, image, bitmap, blur

I am working on a project where I need to apply progressive blur towards center of bitmap. 
Currently I have applied blur with 2 different intensities, one above another with different center radius, but I am not able to get a shooth progressive effect. Please check attached screenshot for more information.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did anything work for you that time?